# PassRole vulnerability for service-linked roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

I am trying to clean up some Roles in our AWS account.. I have cleaned up most of the "customer" created Roles/Policies with the PassRole * vulnerability. I'm wondering how to deal with service linked roles with Passrole *

As an example take the Role "AWSServiceRoleForLambdaReplicator" with the Policy "AWSLambdaReplicator". this Policy has the following section:

```
{
        "Sid": "IamPassRolePermission",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLikeIfExists": {
                "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering is this an issue? Although the Role seems to allow PassRole for any Role to a lambda (inc admin), the Policy also states "This policy is linked to a service and used only with a service-linked role for that service. You cannot attach, detach, modify, or delete this policy."

Is this an instance of the PassRole vulnerability? If so how best can it be mitigated?

edit

What is PassRole vulnerability?

PassRole can be used for privilege escalation, e.g. a User with ReadOnly and PassRole could create an EC2 instance and pass an Admin role to the instance

https://rhinosecuritylabs.com/aws/aws-privilege-escalation-methods-mitigation/

Comment: What is "*the* PassRole vulnerability"

Comment: @luk2302 I've edited my question to include some information on what it is and a link for further reading

Comment: Then I do not understand the point of the question. You are worried users can pass roles to services. Yes, if that policy is attached to your users they can pass roles to lambda. But that policy cannot be attached - so what are you worried about exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue because of the condition in the statement, the passrole will only be used with `lambda.amazonaws.com` if no condition was there then it would become an issue.